# clang with -Weverything flag not catching nonexistent elements in vector

Tags: c++, vector, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I'm learning C++ from Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice Using C++, 2nd Edition book.

The following code snippet:

```cpp
#include "include/std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
  vector<int> v = { 5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8 };
  vector<string> philosopher = { "Kant", "Plato", "Hume", "Kierkegaard" };

  philosopher[2] = 99; // compile-time error should be here, too
  v[2] = "Hume";       // compile-time error presented here as it should

  vector<int> vi(6);
  vector<string> vs(4);

  vi[20000] = 44; // run-time error, but not compile-time error
  cout << "vi.size() == " << vi.size() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Only giving this compile-time error:

```bash
clang++ -std=c++1z -g -Weverything -Werror -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Ofast -march=native -ffast-math src/055_vector.cpp -o bin/055_vector
src/055_vector.cpp:11:7: error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'const char [5]'
        v[2] = "Hume";           // compile-time error presented here as it should
             ^ ~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I enabled error checking with `-std=c++1z -g -Weverything -Werror -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic` commands. But as you can see these lines not giving errors but according to the book, these should also, just like `v[2] = "Hume";`:

```cpp
philosopher[2] = 99;
vi[20000] = 44;
```

If I commenting out the `v[2] = "Hume";` error line from the first  console output and I only compile with the `vi[20000] = 44;` line, it even worse, it compiles without problem, but after when I try run the program:

```bash
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Range_error'
  what():  Range error: 20000
```

How to catch nonexistent elements in vector and if I trying to assign a string to an int in a vector? Looks like `-Weverything` not including this.

Are there any more strict hidden flags for this case in clang, which not inluded under `-Weverything`?

Comment: A compiler is not *obliged* to give warnings or errors for every kind of programming error. (Actually, the cases in which a compiler is *obliged* to give a diagnosis are defined in the standard.) Consider warnings a helping hand. "No warnings" does not equal "no mistakes in the program". -- `vector::operator[]` is not range-checking, use `vector::at()` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`philosopher[2] = 99;` is legal code, it makes the string be a 1-character string and the character has code 99. (probably `'c'`).  This seems unintuitive, but `std::string` was designed decades ago and now it can't be changed without breaking existing code.

The standard does not specify any required diagnostic for `vi[20000] = 44;`.  This is runtime undefined behaviour; if execution never reached that line, it would not be an error.

To catch runtime-errors there are some options, such as running in a debugger, or using clang's address sanitizer, or valgrind.